# Doctrine EventListener onFlush access to old Document

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener, odm

I can access to the updated document in onFlush eventListerner of Doctrine2.
I want complete old document to store it elsewhere as old state.

```
   public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $dm = $eventArgs->getDocumentManager();

        $uow = $dm->getUnitOfWork();
        foreach ($uow->getScheduledDocumentUpdates() as $document) {
            // $document is updated document
            // $changeSet contains only new and old values
            $changeSet = $uow->getDocumentChangeSet($document);

            // I want the whole old document object as $oldDocument
        }       
    }
```

How can I access old document not just change set?

Comment: You should listen for [`preUpdate`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) event: there you can get what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the **preUpdate event**. Example:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getEntity(); // the whole entity
    $changeSet = $event->getEntityChangeSet(); // only changed properties

    // check if password has been changed
    if ($event->hasChangedField('password')) { 
        // do stuff
    }

    /* ... */
}
```